# Unexpected behavior in array comparison

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to compare data in a 2D array that represents a matrix.
As it is a sparse matrix, I created the 2D array compactMatrix, that has the lines and columns where the value matrix entrance is not null.

I'm using this code to make the comparison:

```
    if(compactMatrix[0][i] == compactMatrix[1][k] &&
       compactMatrix[1][i] == compactMatrix[0][k]){

        Do stuff...
    }
```

Where `i` and `k` are the indexes I'm currently looking at in a `for`loop.
For you to know, I debugged and the value of `compactMatrix[0][i]` and `compactMatrix[1][k]`and `compactMatrix[1][i]` and `compactMatrix[0][k]` were indeed equal.

Tried to print the value using

```
    j = compactMatrix[0][i];
    l = compactMatrix[1][i];
    printf("%i %i", &j, &l);
```

but it gives me the pointer address, I guess.

So, I want to know why is it returning `false` in that if clause and how to fix it properly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this `printf("%i %i", &j, &l);` causes UB.

Comment: Don't describe your code but show a  [mcve]

Comment: it should be `printf("%i %i", j, l);`

Comment: You guys really didn't get what I am asking. I'm asking about the if clause, not about the print.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I provided a minimal, complete and verifiable example of my if clause that is giving UB

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is used for just outputting the value it doesn't need an address. Also when you try to print an address in integral formats its an undefined behaviour . The standard requires that you print address with `%p`.

As CS Pei mentioned in the comments What you need probably is this:

```
printf ("%i %i",j,l);// you can use %d and %i interchangeably.
```

Some extra note about `%p` from the standard itself :

> The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to apointer to void.
>   The input item is converted to a pointer value in an
>   implementation-defined manner. If the input item is a value converted
>   earlier during the same program execution, the pointer that results
>   shall compare equal to that value; otherwise the behavior of the %p
>   conversion is undefined.

So if you do use p specifier don't forget to cast the argument to `void*`

Comment: This is not a answer to my  question. And I don't want to print the addres, I tried to print the content just to verify AGAIN that the IF CLAUSE should work, but it's not.

Comment: I don't understand , you yourself just said that the elements of the arrays were indeed equal. The only problem which we could find in the above described question is the problem with printing

Comment: Did you read it all? "So, I want to know why is it returning false in that if clause and how to fix it properly.". It is returning false when it should be returning true.